# Expo Push Notifications: "Error: Couldn't get GCM token on device."

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to receive push notifications with my Expo app, but at this line, the aforementioned error is thrown:

```js
token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
```

I already tried:

- setting up a FireBase account and linking the server API key with
  `expo push:android:upload --api-key <token>`
- downloading the `google-services.json`, linking it in `app.json` and making sure that android.package is set to the correct value
- logging into my expo account with `expo login`
- upgrading Expo to the newest version
- building the app and running it as a standalone app on a physical device

Unfortunately, nothing worked and I'm running out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just solved it by upgrading Expo to version `3.17.24`.